# How can I redirect domain A to domain B without hosting, using only DNS records?

Tags: https, hosting, 301-redirect, redirection, ovh

I want to redirect `domain A` (without hosting space) to `domain B` (301), but when I try https://domainA.com or https://www.domainA.com it ends with `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`. Is it even possible to use only DNS records?

I'm using OVH.com redirection panel and http:// redirect works fine.

Comment: OVH redirects now work for HTTPS too, from what I can tell.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Redirects cannot be done with DNS only.

However, some providers have HTTP redirect services that are configured via same interface as DNS. These support only HTTP. HTTPS support requires valid certificate for the domain.

Therefore if you want to have HTTPS redirects, you need to set up your own server for it.

Comment: There are also third party redirect services which support HTTPS.

Comment: Ok, then I will point to another server with hosting space. Then I will create valid cert for domainA and set up force redirect for https and after that to domainB. @pato. I have heard about cloudflare.com

Answer (score 3):

Another option is such as https://forwarddomain.net/ which (kindly) gives a free redirect service using only DNS records. An example below redirects from `sub.example.com` to `othersite.com`

```
sub.example.com.    IN  CNAME   r.forwarddomain.net
_.sub.example.com.  IN  TXT forward-domain=https://othersite.com/*
```

Comment: Amazing solution! Please keep it going!.

Answer (score 1):

Thats not possible on DNS Side,

But if you use CloudFlare DNS, you can configure the redirect via CF proxy [ https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200172286-Configuring-URL-forwarding-or-redirects-with-Cloudflare-Page-Rules ]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/WeEkd.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/FThb7.png

*Just make sure the domain record use proxy feature.

Answer (score -2):

1. You can go to the DNS Management console (dnsmgmt.msc).
2. Then go to the forward lookup zone.
3. Create zone named domainA.com
4. In the domainA.com zone create a record and name it as "www" then for the IP address of [www.domainb.com](http://www.domainb.com) websites.
5. It should redirect the website without issue.